# unable to see "ADE" option under "Source Code Management" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have setup a new Jenkins instance in docker.
Now am trying to create a new job. But the problem that am facing is my Source Code is in ADE.
But under "Source Code Management" i see only 2 options: 1) None  2) Git.
I dont see "ADE" option.
Is there any Plugin for ADE in jenkins?
Please do help

Comment: What is ADE? Do you have a link? Never heard of it...

Comment: Its a source code build tool similar to GIT, developed and used internally by ORACLE organisation.

Comment: ADE (Advanced Development Environment)

Comment: What Is ADE?

ADE (Advanced Development Environment) provides Software Configuration Management services for Oracle's enterprise software development infrastructure.  It was developed in-house to meet the corporation's unique requirements to integrate development across a wide range of products while facilitating rapid development and maintaining the highest possible quality standards and levels of security.

Comment: Features

    Supports multiple branch and version development
    Based on Oracle RDBMS, and inherits features - fast, secure, scalable
    Supports development models
        Label-based
        tip-of-tree
        shared transactions
        Project Transactions
    Supports integration with the development environment
    Supports integration with related products.
    Secure
    Scalable

Comment: Considering the history of Jenkins/Hudson and Oracle, there's some schadenfreude in learning that Oracle's own CM system is not supported on Jenkins.

Comment: Seems like there was at least [some ADE plugin](https://github.com/hudson2-plugins/ade-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/com/oracle/hudson/plugins) development done for the original Hudson.

Comment: let me have a look into it

Answer (score 0):

I worked at Oracle for some months and I used ade. Since ADE is a propietary SCM from Oracle, it is fully integrated in Oracle products. As far as I know, ADE can´t be integrated with jenkins natively but I think you could create a transaction in your jenkins server. When you need to build in jenkins, you would need to pull the transaction on your machine to the jenkins server. If you can set an observer or listener in jenkins when something changes in your transaction then trigger the build.

I am not sure if this can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I have installed Jenkins in a docker container hosted on my Linux machine. Now the problem am facing is that I am unable to login to my Jenkins instance(UI) as my Unix\Linux user.

When i navigate to "Manage Jenkins >> Security >> Configure Global Security", under "Security Realm", I see an option called "Unix user/group database". If i select that option its asks(prompts) for "Service Name". I enter "sshd" and then click on "Test" button. On doing so it gives the below error: "User ‘jenkins’ needs to belong to group shadow to read /etc/shadow".

I am not sure how to fix it as am very new to docker as well as jenkins. Finally what i want to achieve is "i want to be able to login using my Unix\Linux credentials".